# Application can't be found by iPod Touches?

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, ipod-touch

I released my first application to the App Store. Everything went fine until some people told me that they couldn't find the app. After a little research I noticed that people with iPhones could find and download the app but people with iPod Touches could not. Does anyone know an answer to this?

I have no idea as to why this is happening, I don't know any way of excluding iPod Touches from downloading the app so I probably didn't make this happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any device specific requirements (required capabilities) in Info.plist iTunes will automatically hide the app from devices that can't run it.
Can you post any that you have?

---

If it wasn't available on all devices (or app store portals) then it was most likely still in the processin for app store stage. Once that finished it became available everywhere it's available.

Comment: The app suddenly started working for everyone. It could have been a fault of the App Store but it seems its fixed now. Thanks anyways!